# Store images dataURL on server

Tags: php, mysql, json, data-url

I would like to store multiple images converted to dataURL in our server. What is the best way to do it, for speed and usability?

- Store into a sql database?
- Store all images into a large JSON file?
- Divide images into multiple JSON files?
- Or any suggestion?

I'm asking because I want to create an associative array wich I can easilly work on.

```
echo $img->name;
echo $img->description;
echo '<img src="'.$img->dataURL.'">;
```

**CONCLUSION**

So, the best way is to store the images in the file system itself (thanks to @jszobody) at least for better caching (thanks to @AndrewMcGivery) and store the informations in a database.

Comment: Store images as, uh, images on the filesystem. Or alternatively store the binary data in the database. Binary data in JSON seems... eww.

Comment: Just trying to find the best way, brainstorming ;).

Comment: I like images stored as image files on the filesystem.

Comment: Yes but i'd like to make a simple object with the name, description, notes and it would be easier and cleaner if I just need to write `img.name, img.dataURL, img.desc`

Comment: Store the image on the filesystem. Store the metadata (along with the filename) in a database.

Comment: +1 for storing the image itself on the file system, and relevant info in a database.

Comment: There are all kinds of problems with storing images as dataURLS. One is performance. Your browser can't cache dataURLs, so it has to render every image every time the page loads... and dataURLS block page rendering.